# Xamarin button broken?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile

I make a simple page apps like that

```
<ContentPage.Content>
  <ScrollView>
    <Grid>
        <Button Clicked="test1"/>
        <Button Clicked="test2"/>
    </Grid>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

It's just an exemple, but seem the button cannot be clicked...

Comment: your buttons are positioned directly on top of each other.  If you are using a Grid layout you need to specify rows and columns and where each button should be located.  Otherwise use a StackLayout

Comment: Even if you specified coloumn and rows, it's the same. I just don't post all the code (too long).

Answer (score 0):

Set the height and width to `*` and set the row and column for button. The code below works well.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                     
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Clicked="test1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button Clicked="test2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button Clicked="test3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button Clicked="test4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button Clicked="test5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button Clicked="test6" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Screenshot:

[image]